# Не получается сделать перевод в последующих фрагментах после выбора другой локали приложения

Tags: android

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. В своем приложении я реализую локализацию, но он должен у меня работать отдельно от локалей системы. Я написал с помощью туториалов класс LocaleHelper

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import com.example.core.utils.preferences.AppSharedPreferences
import timber.log.Timber
import java.util.*

class LocaleHelper(private val appPreferences: AppSharedPreferences) {

   fun onAttach(context: Context): Context? {
       val lang = getPersistedData(Locale.getDefault().language)
       Timber.d("Locale/LocaleHelper.onAttach.lang = $lang")
       return setLocale(context, lang!!)
   }

    fun onAttach(context: Context, locale: String): Context? {
        val lang = getPersistedData(locale)
        return setLocale(context, lang!!)
    }

    fun setLocale(context: Context, language: String): Context? {
        persist(language)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language)
        }
        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language)
    }

    private fun getPersistedData(locale: String): String? {
        Timber.d("Locale/LocaleHelper.getPersistData.lang = $locale")
        return appPreferences.loadChangingByUserLocale(locale)
    }

    private fun persist(language: String) {
        appPreferences.saveChangingByUserLocale(language)
    }

    private fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String): Context? {
        val appLocale = Locale(language)
        val configuration = context.resources.configuration

        Locale.setDefault(appLocale)
        configuration.apply {
            setLocale(appLocale)
            setLayoutDirection(appLocale)
        }
        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    private fun updateResourcesLegacy(context: Context, language: String): Context? {
        val appLocale = Locale(language)
        val resource = context.resources
        val configuration = resource.configuration

        Locale.setDefault(appLocale)
        configuration.locale = appLocale
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(appLocale)
        }
        resource.updateConfiguration(configuration, resource.displayMetrics)
        return context
    }
}
```

На начальной странице я сделал выпадающий список, который открывается по клику

private fun preparePopupWindowLangs(): PopupWindow? {
val popup = PopupWindow(view!!.context).apply {
width = 250
height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
isOutsideTouchable = true
isFocusable = true
contentView = contentList()
}
logger.preparePopupWindow()
return popup
}

```
    private fun contentList(): ListView {
        val localesAdapter = LanguagesPopupAdapter(context!!, prepareLocalesList(viewModel.localesNames))
        localesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        val listView = ListView(context).apply {
            adapter = localesAdapter
            onItemClickListener = popupOnItemClick()
        }
        return listView
    }

    private fun prepareLocalesList(@StringRes array: Array<Int>): List<String> {
        val locales: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        array.forEachIndexed { index, locale ->
            locales.add(index, resources.getString(locale))
        }
        return locales
    }

    private fun popupOnItemClick(): OnItemClickListener {
        val itemClick = OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val fadeInAnimation: Animation =
                AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fragment_fade_enter)
            fadeInAnimation.duration = 10
            view!!.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation)
            val selectedItemText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.language_tv).text.toString()
            langs_popup.text = selectedItemText
            popup!!.dismiss()
            changeLocale(viewModel.localesIndexes[position])
        }
        return itemClick
    }
```

По выбору из списка я меняю текста

```
 private fun changeTextAfterLanguageSelection(lang: String) {
        val context = viewModel.localeHelper.setLocale(context!!, lang)
        val resources = context!!.resources
        login_tv.text = resources.getString(R.string.field_header_login)
        login_et.hint = resources.getString(R.string.hint_login)
        password_tv.text = resources.getString(R.string.field_header_password)
        password_et.hint = resources.getString(R.string.hint_password)
        auth_progress_button.setButtonName(context, R.string.btn_enter)
        prepareLocalesList(viewModel.localesNames)
        setPopupTitleText()
    }
```

Еще я добавил метод, чтобы во фрагменте менялся текст

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(viewModel.localeHelper.onAttach(context)!!)
    }
```

В активити добавил метод установки локали для приложения

```
 override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(localeHelper.onAttach(newBase!!, appPreferences.loadChangingByUserLocale("ru")!!)))
   }
```

В итоге я получаю следующее: в эмуляторе с API 22 все работает как надо, а вот уже на API 29 при переходе на другой фрагмент перевод не осуществляется, а работает лишь та локаль, которая была при запуске приложения.
Знаю, что есть вариант перезапуска активити при выборе языка, но такой подход для моей задачи не подходит.
Я реализую технологию SingleActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я попытался разобраться понять что происходит в вашем коде, но это оказалось не так просто, как хотелось бы. Многие функции совершенно непонятно откуда взяты и зачем приведены...

Я делал смену языка по выбору пользователя в SingleActivity приложении. Это было очень просто. Код после выбора языка:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = newLocale;
context.getResources ().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics ());
Intent intent = activity.getIntent ();
activity.finish ();
context.startActivity (intent);
```

Да, мы пересоздаем активити, а значит придется грамотно сохранять текущее состояние, и в случае с одной активити и фрагментами это, мне кажется, очень даже несложно

Comment: А можно ли сделать так, чтобы при перезагрузке активити визуально не было видно "вспышки"? Просто в промежутке между onDestroy -> onCreate происхдит на доли секунды исчезновение view и на белом фоне это видится как мгновенная черная вспышка

Comment: Хм... боюсь прям бесшовно подмену не провернуть. Если очень важно сделать красиво, без вспышки, то можно вызывать SplashScreen, который в свою очередь уже вызовет вашу активити, и накрутить на эти смены анимации в соответствии с теми, что используются в проекте. В итоге сначала красиво перейдете в свое лого, потом красиво в основной экран. Но учитывая, что смена языка явление крайне редкое, мне кажется пользователи не очень-то обозляться на секундное моргание один за вечность =)